# I want to get different tags of App.config File in C#

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have to get string inside Setting-> Value in C#. How to reach there through code and fetch that value from App.config file. Please help me. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
  <section name="MyApplication.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>


<applicationSettings>
<MyApplication.Properties.Settings>

  **<setting name="ConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
    <value>server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=root;database=MyApplication_db;</
  </setting>**

</VASI_Application.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var section = (ClientSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("applicationSettings/MyApplication.Properties.Settings");
var settingElement = section.Settings.Get("ConnectionString");
var settingValue = settingElement.Value.ValueXml.InnerText;

// settingValue equals "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=root;database=MyApplication_db;"
```

First, you retrieve the `ClientSettingsSection` section. The name of the section is a combination of the name of the `"applicationSettings"` section and its inner `"MyApplication.Properties.Settings"` section. Then, you retrieve the actual settings by calling `Settings.Get("ConnectionString")` on the returned `ClientSettingsSection` instance. Finally, you can use the `Value.ValueXml.InnerText` property of the returned setting to get to the actual value.

By the way, you have two small errors in your XML file:

1. The `<MyApplication.Properties.Settings>` element in incorrectly closed with `</VASI_Application.Properties.Settings>`
2. The `<value>` element is not correctly closed with `</value>`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the property ConnectionString?

As documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx), usually you can access it in this way:

`var setting = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;`

By the way, your application tag starts with `MyApplication.Properties.Settings` but ends with `VASI_Application.Properties.Settings`

Answer (score 0):

If you do actually want to go ahead with a custom config file section like in your example then you will need to follow this Microsoft guide for creating custom configuration sections.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

If you get stuck following this guide then raise another question.